# PLS-00103 Eroor when trying to run a PL/SQL script

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I'm trying to run the following `PL/SQL` script :

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cr IS SELECT NOMLOG, NOMPOSTE, DATEACH, DATEINS from LOGICIEL L, INSTALLATION I, POSTE P where I.NLOG = L.NLOG AND P.NPOSTE = I.NPOSTE;
    inst INSTALLATION%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cr;
    FETCH cr INTO inst;
    WHILE cr%FOUND LOOP
            IF inst.DATEACH IS NULL AND inst.DATEINS IS NOT NULL THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('Date d''achat inconnue pour le logiciel' || inst.NOMLOG || ' sur ' || inst.NOMPOSTE);
            ELSEIF inst.DATEACH IS NOT NULL AND inst.DATEINS IS NULL THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('Pas de date d''installation pour le logiciel' || inst.NOMLOG || ' sur ' || inst.NOMPOSTE);
            ELSEIF inst.DATEACH IS NULL AND inst.DATEINS IS NULL THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('Date d''installation et date d''achat sont inconnue pour le logiciel' || inst.NOMLOG || ' sur ' || inst.NOMPOSTE);
            ELSE
                IF inst.DATEACH < inst.DATEINS
                    dbms_output.put_line('Logiciel' || inst.NOMLOG || ' sur ' || inst.NOMPOSTE || ', attente ' || inst.DATEACH - inst.DATEINS || ' jour(s)');
                ELSE
                    dbms_output.put_line('Logiciel' || inst.NOMLOG || ' installé sur ' || inst.NOMPOSTE || ', ' || inst.DATEACH - inst.DATEINS || ' jour(s) avant d''être acheté!');
                END IF
            END IF;
        FETCH cr INTO inst;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cr;
END;
/
```

But I'm getting this error message :

```
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INST" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "INST" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 10, column 36:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:
; and or
The symbol "and" was substituted for "" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 10, column 64:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:
; and or
ORA-06550: line 12, column 11:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INST" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "INST" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 12, column 57:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:
; and or
ORA-06550: line 16, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_OUTPUT" when expecting one of the
following:
. ( * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem then
<an exponent (**)> and or || multiset
The symbol "." was substituted for "DBMS
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You may want to consider changing the type of `inst` to `cr%ROWTYPE` to make this code resilient to table structure changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the := operator in conditional sentences. Try only the equal symbol =

```
IF inst.DATEACH = '' AND inst.DATEINS <> '' THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('Date d''achat inconnue pour le logiciel' || inst.NOMLOG || ' sur ' || inst.NOMPOSTE);
            ELSEIF inst.DATEACH <> '' AND inst.DATEINS = '' THEN
```

...and so on

Comment: please check the modification I made to my post.

Comment: Ok, first of all, the correct comand is ELSIF, not ELSEIF. In line 16, you're missing the THEN word. In line 19, you're missing a semicolon (;) after END IF. Those are just syntax errors, will have to look into the logic next.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 8 to...

```
IF inst.DATEACH = '' AND inst.DATEINS <> '' THEN
```

Also change all your other boolean expressions to use just an equals sign instead of :=

And have you thought about saying something like...

```
IF inst.DATEACH is not null AND inst.DATEINS <> '' THEN
```

Comment: please check the modification I made to my post.